# Difficulty closing front door

Tags: doors, hanging, finishing

[image: door bell wire]

Hi I have a new home and the front door is difficult to close.  They have run the doorbell wire along the inside of the upper frame (as seen in the pic) and the door rubs against it.  I’m worried that wire will eventually get worn down and in general it sucks having to lean on the door to close it.  My kids are also have a hard time closing it too, which means the door is occasionally left open.

[entire door](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znsfu.jpg)

The door was not hung squarely as I think you can see in the picture and it looks like I could fix this by shimming or somehow bringing that bottom left corner out just a 1/16th. I have about an eighth to work with at the bottom left and even more in other areas.  I have very limited experience hanging doors and I’m hoping someone can help with a quick fix tip that won’t involve rehanging/reframing the door.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check that the hinge screws are all tight.

Comment: Not just tight, but long enough... Put at least one 3" screw in the top hinge and see if that improves things. (Note that you have to drive the screw pretty hard, so a plain old screwdriver will make the job tough.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are right the cable was installed by a drunken sailor. First things first. Drill a hole with a long skinny drillbit through the doorframe (home improvement store) which is a little bigger than the cable than use a wire and some tape to fish the wire through the hole and back to the bell. The bell has low voltage and is save to touch (I am not liable !!!). Take pictures before you uninstall the wires. Now see where you at with your door.

Comment: And yes, the wire will absolutely get worn down and fail. That is a totally unacceptable way to have done that. I would fix that before shimming the door.

Comment: Ya you are both right, the real fix is to re-fish the wire.  Unfortunately I’m not in a position to do that yet.  I will check the hinges like Jasen suggested and report back.